# Only Create new row, if a specific column is updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL-Trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG_Update]
ON [dbo].[DIENSTLEISTUNG]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

SET  NOCOUNT ON;


        INSERT INTO [DIENSTLEISTUNG] 
                 (DESCRIPTION, QUANTITY, 
                  PRICE, AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
                  AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
                  UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_DATE,
                  PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ITEMNUMBER,
                  PRIORITY, VALID)
        SELECT  DESCRIPTION, QUANTITY, PRICE AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
                AZ_SA,AZ_SO,SERVICETYPE_ID, UPDATE_USER,GETDATE(),
                PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ITEMNUMBER, PRIORITY, 'Y',VALID
        FROM INSERTED

        UPDATE  SERVICE
        SET  VALID = 'N' 
        FROM    SERVICE
                INNER JOIN INSERTED ON INSERTED.ID = SERVICE.ID



SET  NOCOUNT OFF;      
END
```

The Trigger copies an entire row with a new ID if a change in the original row happens.
So far so good. I want that the Trigger only creates a new row if `PRICE` or `DESCRIPTION` is updated. If i do a Update on `PRIORITY` or `ITEMNUMER` or the other columns the trigger should only update the row, but not create a new row.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INSERTED and DELETED tables:

```
INSERT INTO [DIENSTLEISTUNG] 
         (DESCRIPTION, QUANTITY, 
          PRICE, AZ_MO, AZ_DI,AZ_MI,AZ_DO,AZ_FR,
          AZ_SA,AZ_SO,DIENSTLEISTUNGSART_ID,
          UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_DATE,
          PERMISSIONS, KONTRAKTPOSITION,ITEMNUMBER,
          PRIORITY, VALID)
SELECT  i.DESCRIPTION, i.QUANTITY, i.PRICE, i.AZ_MO, i.AZ_DI,i.AZ_MI,i.AZ_DO,i.AZ_FR,
        i.AZ_SA,i.AZ_SO,i.SERVICETYPE_ID, i.UPDATE_USER,GETDATE(),
        i.PERMISSIONS, i.KONTRAKTPOSITION,i.ITEMNUMBER, i.PRIORITY, 'Y',i.VALID
FROM INSERTED i
     JOIN deleted d ON i.ID=d.ID
WHERE i.PRICE<>d.PRICE
      or i.DESCRIPTION<>d.DESCRIPTION

    UPDATE  S
    SET  s.VALID = 'N',
         s.priority=i.priority,
         s.QUANTITY =i.QUANTITY,
         ...  
    FROM    SERVICE s
            JOIN INSERTED i ON I.ID = S.ID
            JOIN deleted d ON i.ID=d.ID
    WHERE i.PRICE=d.PRICE
          or i.DESCRIPTION=d.DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. If i try that i get an Error in the Browser: The Datarow that you are trying to update is no longer exists in the datasource, or the datarow is out of visible page. Please refresh grid.

Comment: @Paks It isn't sql-server's error but client's. Maybe you try to `update` the table after execution of the trigger? Try to `UPDATE` row from ssms to be sure that the trigger work properly.

Comment: I can Update Price and Description. So far it works fine. The trigger copies the entire row with a new id and new price or Description. But i cant update Priority or other colmuns.

Comment: @Paks Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Now I updated  the script (its `UPDATE` part) - you need to add all columns which you want to update instead of `...`. Hope, this'll be helpful.

Comment: @ Igor i tried that already with s.priority = i.priority. But still the same. I can only Update Price and Description. But i can not update the other columns. I dont know why

Comment: @Parks, look at this conditions `WHERE i.PRICE=d.PRICE or i.DESCRIPTION=d.DESCRIPTION` because of them the row will be updated just when `PRICE` and `DESCRIPTION` were not changed. If you don't need this conditions just erase them.

Comment: Problem is the s.VALID = 'N'. If i erase  the where condition then the update works but VALID = 'N' should only be set if PRICE or DESCRIPTION is updated, because if i Update PRICE or DESCRIPTION the trigger creates a new row. The new row is setted to VALID = 'Y' and the old row is setted to VALID = 'N'. If i do an update for example on priority, the new row is setted to VALID =  'N'. This should not happen. It should stay VALID = 'Y'

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the COLUMNS_UPDATED property. The result values depend on the structure of your table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx

or you could compare the values in the deleted and inserted tables.